# "not in dispatcher" - issues connecting a validator peer to genesis validator

Tags: validation, authorization, hyperledger, peer, hyperledger-sawtooth

I have been banging my head for a while on this one.
So, I have successfully (maybe) created a running sawtooth validator with a settings-tp and poet-validator-registry (all containers from scratch).

I created it with a config-genesis.batch - then "proposal create" with poet and a public key pem etc. for a config.batch - then "poet registration create" for a poet.batch - "proposal create" again with the additional poet settings which give a poet-settings.batch.

Basically, I am copying for the most part the docker-compose for poet default, but now rolled with my own containers from scratch (I want to know how everything pieces together in detail).

Anyway, one of those details is regarding keys and auth... it's finally running, the settings-tp and poet-val-reg are happy with it and communicating normally and then it makes a genesis block as it should.

However, I then try to connect another validator to it as a peer...

"No chain head and not the genesis node: starting in peering mode" - GREAT!

However, when it tries to connect:

```
[2018-05-10 10:30:10.542 INFO     dispatch] Can't send message PING_RESPONSE back to ee58844c071426276de533cadfafbd3c2448604e59fd81f4758edc07b5beea89476a6252e0a2144d43f14e06bf90c57dd2613562221954e3b2eddc6d2fcd9ef6 because connection OutboundConnectionThread-tcp://192.168.1.200:8800 not in dispatcher
[2018-05-10 10:30:10.542 INFO     dispatch] Can't send last message AUTHORIZATION_VIOLATION back to ee58844c071426276de533cadfafbd3c2448604e59fd81f4758edc07b5beea89476a6252e0a2144d43f14e06bf90c57dd2613562221954e3b2eddc6d2fcd9ef6 because connection OutboundConnectionThread-tcp://192.168.1.200:8800 not in dispatcher
```

It's so hard to find explanations on this, only places I can find anything is the original refs in the source code and I'm not going to backwards engineer that anytime soon.

My settings for the validators on startup are:

```
The usual binds to 0.0.0.0
peering dynamic
scheduler serial
network trust
```

Any help would be so soooo appreciated!

Many thanks in advance :)

Aaron.

Answer (score 1):

The usual problem with the

```
Can't send message PING_RESPONSE back to . . . because connection ... not in dispatcher
```

is configuring the peer endpoints

1) If you are using Ubuntu directly instead of Docker, use the Validator's hostname or IP address instead of the default ("validator"), which only works with Docker, or "localhost", which may not be routable

2) If you are using Docker, make sure the Docker ports are mapped to the Ubuntu OS, and that the OS IP address/port is routable between the two machines. Check the `expose:` and `ports:` entries in your `docker-compose.yaml` file or similar file.

3) Verify network connectivity to the remote machine with `ping`

4) Verify port connectivity `telnet aremotehostname 8800` (replace `aremotehostname` with the remote peer's hostname or IP address)

5) Check peer configuration in your `/etc/sawtooth/validator.toml` files. Check the `peering` and `endpoint` lines. Check the `seeds` line (for dynamic peering) or `peers` line (for static peering)